# Google Charts is not displaying last row in the data array?

Tags: google-visualization

I have data array with 45 rows but only 44 rows are visible on the screen after I am hide columns between 8 and 14 using "setColumns" and then re-enable any of the columns between 8 and 14:

The 45th row has following data:

```
0:{wf: "10 May 2018, 14:44:36"}
1:{wf: ""}
2:{wf: ""}
3:{wf: ""}
4:{wf: ""}
5:{wf: ""}
6:{wf: ""}
7:{wf: ""}
8:{wf: "69.9"}
9:{wf: "73.2"}
10:{wf: "65.2"}
11:{wf: "73.2"}
12:{wf: "82.8"}
13:{wf: "0"}
14:{wf: "28.6"}
```

To perform column toggle I use following commands:

```
    performColumnToggle: function (col)
    {
        // use original unfiltered data
        _view = new google.visualization.DataView(_original_data);

        // get a key due to splice not keeping keys one delete
        var key = $.inArray(col, _toggledColumns);

        if (_columns[col]['status'] === 1) {
            _columns[col]['status'] = 0;
            // delete by key because splice doesn't keep keys on delete 
            _toggledColumns.splice(key, 1);

        } else {
            _columns[col]['status'] = 1;
            // insert new items with a key and push other columns
            _toggledColumns.splice(col, 0, col);
        }
        // set columns to display
        _view.setColumns(_toggledColumns);
        console.log(_chart.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows()); // keeps returns 44 rather then 45.
        _dashboard.draw(_view);
    }
```

---

I set _original_data when I first initiate the chart and when I have to update the data in the chart. When I perform console.log(_original_data) I see all 45 rows.

```
    init_chart: function ()
    { 
        _data = new google.visualization.DataTable(_tableData);
        _original_data = _data;

        // some other code ....
    }

    updateData: function ()
    { 
        _tableData = data;
        _data = new google.visualization.DataTable(_tableData);
        _original_data = _data;

        // some other code ....
    }
```

---

Below is an example code

https://jsfiddle.net/Spiker/g0k714h7/

To trigger error take following steps:

1. Scroll down the page you will notice that we have 45 rows with last row having time date "10 May 2018, 14:44:36"
2. Scroll back up and click on "Select/Diselect All". You can scroll down the table to see that now we have 44 rows
3. Either Click on "Select/Diselect All" or "record8". Scroll down the page to see that we still have 44 rows in the table

Comment: No, I am not. I have updated the description with information on how I am performing set columns.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: _view.getNumberOfRows() returns 45 rows but 44 are shown

Comment: Would it help to see json that I am feeding into google charts?

Comment: I have added a json that I am having a problem with. I will try to put a working graph online for others to see later today.

Comment: I have added dummy code on the jsfiddle available in the description.

Comment: My answer uses `setColumns()` from `dataView` class just like OP code posted in question. The difference is that `hideColumns()` is used for the second state where there are less columns. It works flawlessly with 90 rows (2x OP code) and toggles from 15 columns and 8 columns.  There are no side effects or buggy behavior. Did I miss a requirement because I read: *"I am after a solution for my problem - a code"*

Comment: zer00ne, I have tried reusing what you did, by directly pasting setColumns and hideColumns but it still kept hiding the last column. What solved it was _chart.setView({
  columns: _toggledColumns
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem appears to occur in function --> `switchOffAllColumns`

there must be some sort of bug with the view

setting the view columns on the `ChartWrapper`, rather than the `DataView`,
corrects the issue

in `switchOffAllColumns`, change the following line...

```
_view.setColumns(_toggledColumns);
```

to...

```
_chart.setView({
  columns: _toggledColumns
});
```

see following working fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/WhiteHat/o0j70y9r/

note: `jsapi` should no longer be used, changed above fiddle to use `loader.js` load statement...

Answer (score 3):

---

## **[DataView Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataview-class)**

### [**`.hideColumns()` Method**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods_2)

---

`DataView Class` is a special version of the DataTable Class. Its main purpose is to present a part(s) of the DataTable(s). OP code needs to toggle columns with the method that compliments [**`.setColumns()`**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods_2) which is [**`.hideColumns()`**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods_2).

In **Demo 1** below there is a ternary that toggles the columns from `[0,...14]` to `[8...14]` columns by using  both **`set/hideColumns()`**  methods. The table has 90 rows and it persists at 90 between toggling of columns.

**Example**

---

```
var dView = *status === 'on' ?
 view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]) : 
 view.hideColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
```

---

<sup>⭐</sup> **Demo 2** (located at the bottom of this post,) isn't a solution but it could help the OP code should you decide on not using **Demo 1**.

---

### Demo 1

---

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 15px;
  color: red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
    html {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      font: 400 16px/1.1 Raleway;
    }
    
    body {
      position: relative;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    main {
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .btn {
      width: 11ch;
      font: inherit;
    }
    
    .btn.on::after {
      content: '\a0ON';
    }
    
    .btn.off::after {
      content: '\a0OFF';
    }
    
    .heavy {
      font-weight: 900;
    }
    
    .darkBkg {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .active {
      background: rgba(200, 150, 20, 0.3);
      color: #000;
    }
    
    .tomato {
      color: tomato
    }
    
    .font {
      font-family: Raleway;
    }
    
    .right {
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    .big {
      font-size: 20px
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <button class='btn off' type='button'>VIEW</button>
    <figure id='table'></figure>
  </main>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['table']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

    var cssClassNames = {
      'headerRow': 'heavy font',
      'tableRow': '',
      'oddTableRow': 'darkBkg',
      'selectedTableRow': 'active',
      'hoverTableRow': 'active',
      'headerCell': 'font',
      'tableCell': 'right font',
      'rowNumberCell': 'big heavy tomato font'
    };
    var options = {
      backgroundColor: {
        fill: 'transparent'
      },
      allowHtml: true,
      showRowNumber: true,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      'cssClassNames': cssClassNames
    };

    $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
      $(this).toggleClass('on off');
      var status = $(this).hasClass('on') ? 'on' : 'off';
      console.log(status);
      drawTable(status);
    });


    function drawTable(status) {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'START');
      data.addColumn('date', 'END');
      data.addColumn('string', 'DESC');
      data.addColumn('number', '0');
      data.addColumn('number', '1');
      data.addColumn('number', '2');
      data.addColumn('number', '3');
      data.addColumn('number', '4');
      data.addColumn('number', 'EXT 0');
      data.addColumn('number', 'EXT 1');
      data.addColumn('number', 'EXT 2');
      data.addColumn('number', 'EXT 3');
      data.addColumn('number', 'COL 0');
      data.addColumn('number', 'COL 1');
      data.addColumn('number', 'COL 2');

      var time = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
        formatType: 'short'
      });

      data.addRows([
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0],
        [new Date(2017, 4, 12), new Date(2019, 4, 12), 'Current', 01, 0.335, 487, 5, 63.20, 52, 23, 105.3, 60, 0.001, 111, -1],
        [new Date(1996, 0, 18), new Date(1996, 6, 4), 'Archive', 01, 1.30, 56, 3, 7.08, 88, 23, 98.5, 28, 0.010, 212, 1],
        [new Date(2024, 1, 29), new Date(2028, 1, 29), 'Leap', 01, 0.00, 596, 4, 162.2, 971, 23, 92.3, 4, 0.100, 121, 0]
      ]);

      var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

      var dView = status === 'on' ? view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]) : view.hideColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);

      table.draw(view, options);
    }
  </script>
  <!--<script src='gvis-api.js'></script>-->
</body>

</html>
```

---

<sup>⭐</sup>Although I strongly suggest that you use the `hideColumns()` from **Google Visualization API**, I'd like to address this:

> *"// delete by key because splice doesn't keep keys on delete "*

[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value) returns whatever it deletes. So you call on `splice()` and store its return in a `var`, `const`, `array`, `object`, etc.

---

### Demo 2

---

```js
var columnArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

var removedArray = columnArray.splice(0, 8);

console.log('Removed Column Array: ' + removedArray);
console.log('Remaining Column Array: ' + columnArray);

var restoredArray = removedArray.concat(columnArray);

console.log('Restored Column Array: ' + restoredArray);
```